# Cancel All Currently Running RequestAnimationFrames

Tags: javascript, requestanimationframe

I am calling many requestAnimationFrames at the same time. How would I cancel all of the requestAnimationFrames such that none are running anymore?

Comment: You shouldn't do this in the first place. Use a single `tick()` function; that way you can easily stop everything.

Comment: @ChrisG Could you please explain how I could do that?

Comment: That depends on the code you currently have.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can call `requestAnimationFrame`, store the returned id, and then call `cancelAnimationFrame` for all positive integers less than that number.

```
function cancelAllAnimationFrames(){
   var id = window.requestAnimationFrame(function(){});
   while(id--){
     window.cancelAnimationFrame(id);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`window.requestAnimatioFrame(()=>{})` returns a number to be used with `window.cancelAnimationFrame(number)`. So, store the numbers in an array, and then iterate over the array canceling the numbers.

Via MDN:

[window.requestAnimatioFrame](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame)

[window.cancelAnimationFrame](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/cancelAnimationFrame)